# Libgit2sharp- NoMemory exception on fetch

Tags: git, c#-4.0, libgit2sharp

I've been running round in circles for days now, I'm trying to implement a "pull" command which I understand libgit2sharp doesn't implement directly. I understand that I have to fetch from the remote and then merge this. I came up with the following code:

```
this._repo = new Repository(workingDir);
Credentials credentials = new Credentials() {Username = this._username, Password = this._password};
Remote remote = this._repo.Network.Remotes["origin"];
FetchOptions fetchOptions = new FetchOptions();
fetchOptions.Credentials = credentials;
var branch = @"refs/heads/TestBranch:refs/remotes/origin/TestBranch";
this._repo.Network.Fetch(remote, new string[] { branch }, fetchOptions);
//this._repo.Fetch(this._repo.Head.Name);
//this._repo.Fetch(remote.Name, fetchOptions);
//this._repo.Network.Fetch(remote, fetchOptions);  //this._repo.Network.Remotes["origin"], new FetchOptions() { Credentials = new Credentials() { Password = this._password, Username = this._username }});
```

I've left in the comments to show all the other variations of Fetch I've tried- but no matter what I try I always get the same error:

```
An error was raised by libgit2. Category = NoMemory (User).

Out of memory
```

The only time I've managed to not get this error was when I didn't enter my credentials and I got a 401 return code.

This is using a remote BitBucket account over HTTPS, I found 1 similar problem with BitBucket to do with the username being in the `remote` entry however this was supposed to be fix and still didn't work when I removed the username anyway.

Comment: it reads as if the out of memory exception is occurring on the other end.   What can you do about it?

Comment: If that's the case, then I would also expect to have the same issues when I pull/fetch from git Bash, this isn't the case however, from git Bash it works as normal, as do other commands from the code I've written (for example pushes)

Comment: but you are not getting an outOfMemoryException, you are getting a message from the service that a NoMemory error occurred.  oh well... good luck

Comment: Either your memory space is very fragmented or...this is a bug ;-) Could you please open an **[issue](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/new)** in the project tracker? However, in order to correctly fix this, a repro case would be required. Would you be ok to share the repository details you're trying to fetch from?

Comment: @TMcKeown: no, this is not a message from the service, this is a message from LibGit2Sharp.

Comment: ok, i dont use it... so i wouldn't know.

Comment: Ok nulltoken, will do, I have tested this on 2 different pc's with differing versions of VS 2012 and the same error happens on both. I'll set up another account to be used for testing and pass on the details.

Comment: Open issue here: https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/641